# VAST 2.0 mid-roll and overlay implementation

Tags: javascript, html, ads, vast, ott

We are implementing into our video player the VAST 2.0 png/jpeg banner overlay and the mid-roll video advertisement.

**My question is:** From where the time information comes when (during the movie or series episode watching) the mid-roll video should be played or the overlay banner should be displayed. I was expecting the `VAST XML` has already that information included, but it seems that it should be either player decision or it comes from other source - e.g. it is specified within the movie metadata downloaded from OTT server.

**Second question:** What is the typical mid-roll video behaviour? Is the advertisement played in specific point in time, which means when user jumps in video (using FF/RW on his remote control) I have to play mid-roll (this can be pretty annoying) or I simply count the time the user watches the video and when it is over defined value the mid-roll video is played.

Answer (score 1):

The link may be helpful:
http://openx.openvideoads.org/openx/www/delivery/fc.php?script=bannerTypeHtml:vastInlineBannerTypeHtml:vastInlineHtml&zones=pre-roll:0.0-0%3D50&nz=1&source=&r=R0.05822725687175989&block=1&format=vast&charset=UTF-8

This is a simple VAST xml file. The id of this advertisement is "pre-roll:0.0-0". The test shows that it can be downloaded from the following link:
http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/open-video-ads/ova-for-jw-player-5/22848/a-simple-example

As you can see, the player parses this ad as a pre-roll ad.

So, `VAST xml publisher` can define what are the: ad type, pre-roll, mid-roll or post-roll in ad ID tag.

Maybe, the type can be defined in other tags in VAST xml.

Answer (score -1):

btw, another example:
http://static.openvideoads.org/qa/latest/ova.flowplayer/examples/xml-wrapper/example1-01.html
http://static.openvideoads.org/tests/vast-wrapper-test.xml

I think you could get information from these links and the links in my above answer

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.